# Finding the MAC address of my router's WAN interface

Tags: networking, router, wan, network-interface

As I understand, a router has at least two network interfaces: LAN and WAN. The IP address of the LAN interface is private, and the IP address of the WAN interface is public.

- Is the IP address of the WAN interface of my router my public IP address?
- How can I find the MAC address of the router's WAN interface?

Comment: The router configuration pages should show this if the router is a decent quality router. My router (Cisco RV series) does show this.

Comment: all information that exist on the router device are  unclear or erased,i want to know if i can see this mac adress in the router admin(already i see the mac address of the LAN,but in wan configuration there is not the information about the mac address of wan interface),my device is dsl124

Comment: @John WHAT ABOUT the first question?

Comment: It the router firmware was erased, it must be a very inexpensive router. Routers should backup and retain their firmware.

Comment: i did not understand what you mean

Comment: A decent router should back up its firmware so it cannot be totally erased. Then the router will have a record of its MAC address.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The IP address of your router's WAN interface is *usually* your public IP address, but in some cases your router may be behind a second NAT gateway. For example, if you had a separate broadband "modem" and you didn't realize it wasn't just a modem, but a NAT gateway router in its own right. In that case, the upstream modem/router combo box's WAN IP address would be more likely to be your public IP address. Another example is if your ISP runs a NAT gateway between the Internet and their customers. ISPs are sometimes known as "carriers", so this is known as "Carrier-Grade NAT" (CGNAT). In that case, the CGNAT gateway's upstream IP address would be your public IP address.
2. MAC addresses are a concept from Ethernet and Ethernet-like interfaces. If your router has an Ethernet WAN port, then it will have a MAC address, that will usually show up in the web-based admin UI, as well as on a label on the bottom or back of the router. **HOWEVER** if your router does NOT have an Ethernet or Ethernet-like WAN port, then it will NOT have a MAC address. You said your router is a "dsl124", which I take to mean a "D-Link DSL-124 Wireless N300 ADSL2+ Modem Router". That device does not appear to have an Ethernet WAN port. Since it has a built-in ADSL2+ modem, it's WAN port is the modem's DSL (telephone line) port.

Comment: @user84999 Your router DOES have a WAN port, it's just a DSL WAN port, not an Ethernet WAN port. Read the user manual (you can always find online PDFs of user manuals) if you're not sure. Or just look at the ports on your router and see if any of them are labeled "WAN" and are wide enough to be an 8P8C (RJ-45) connector. Your box probably has a port labeled "DSL", with a narrower 6P6C (RJ-11, RJ-12) telephone line connector.

Comment: ok now as i see in my router there is not a port for wan ,there are just lan 1,2,3,, AND DLS PoRT,but  if it 's does not have a wan port how i can access to internet?  or why i can use it for internet? because  as i know the wan interface is the responsible for connecting to internet

Comment: @user84999 You plug that DSL port into the "modem" port of a DSL filter/splitter, and from there into a landline telephone line. Then you call up your landline telephone company and subscribe to their DSL internet service. Because this device has a built-in DSL modem and no Ethernet WAN port, it is only good for DSL. It is not designed to be used with DOCSIS (cable modem Internet service) or GPON (fiber optic Internet service) or 4G/LTE/5G wireless Internet service, or any other kind of Internet service. You could use it as an extra AP, but not as your main router.

Comment: thank you so much ,also i have one question,now my router does not have the wan interface , so why in my router admin i see some  information about wan  interface, in the wan configuration there is the ip address and the statues:enabled   !!

Comment: does the wan here is for the dsl modem?

Comment: @user84999 Yes, your device's WAN interface is its built-in DSL modem's DSL interface.